# Generated data binding class has two methods with same name, causing error

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-databinding

I have two attributes with name "attribute_short" and "attribute_long".

My getter and setter.

```
@Bindable
    public float getAttribute_long() {
        return attribute_long;
    }

    public void setPricePerBoxSingle_long(float attribute_long) {
        this.attribute_long= attribute_long;
        notifyPropertyChanged(com.foo.bar.baz.BR.attribute_long);
    }

@Bindable
    public float getAttribute_short() {
        return attribute_short;
    }

    public void setPricePerBoxSingle_short(float attribute_short) {
        this.attribute_short= attribute_short;            
        notifyPropertyChanged(com.foo.bar.baz.BR.attribute_short);
    }
```

And two edit texts:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/attributeInput_short"
    ...
    android:text="@={values.attribute_short}" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/attributeInput_long"
    ...
    android:text="@={values.attribute_long}" />
```

In the generated data binding class, it happens to have two methods with the same name, which is causing error.

```
private android.databinding.InverseBindingListener attributeInpu = new android.databinding.InverseBindingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChange() {
            float callbackArg_0 = com.sample.Values.getText(attributeInput_short);
...

private android.databinding.InverseBindingListener attributeInpu = new android.databinding.InverseBindingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange() {
                float callbackArg_0 = com.sample.Values.getText(attributeInput_long);
...
```

Error:

```
Error:(196, 56) error: variable attributeInpu is already defined in class FragmentInputBinding
```

How can I solve this duplicated generated method name problem?

Comment: I have faced the same problem. But it has solved by renaming variable in xml

Answer (score 4):

IMHO this could be related to this reported issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212492

Comment: Making the view Id a little shorter helped .

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the InverseBindingListener variable names are autogenerated based on the view id. As @BruceWayne said, the views id's need to be shorter. I had the same problem and that was the solution for me.